# How to work with subfolders in RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make this rewrite rule to work. What i want is (incoming url):

```
http://hostname.com/mywebsite

http://hostname.com/mywebsite/test

http://hostname.com/mywebsite/something/another
```

to (behind the scene):

```
http://hostname.com/app.php

http://hostname.com/app.php/test

http://hostname.com/app.php/something/another
```

The common thing is "mywebsite" that needs to be ignored but url still shows it

Below rewrite rule does not work so please help

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^mywebsite(.*) /app.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any help would be really good. Thanks!

Comment: I don't about RewriteRule (syntax looks a lot like IIRF), but I think you want to update your last line to "RewriteRule /mywebsite(.*) /app.php$1 [QSA,R]"

Comment: Can you see in your server logs what the result for an example request is?

Comment: I cant use [R]. When i use with [L] it redirects to app.php but it says route /mywebsite not found :(

Comment: Looking at a few examples online, it looks like the comparer path shouldn't start with a /, so you'd end up with something like this: RewriteRule ^mywebsite(.*)$ /app.php/$1

Comment: No its still not working. I have edited question to make it more clear. Thanks for helping, i still need a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a more reliable and pretty simple solution is as follows:

Consider the two cases:

**Case 1:** If you want a full URL redirection use the following Rewrite Rule

```
RewriteEngine On
#Redirect to app.php/the-rest-of-param
RewriteRule ^mywebsite(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/app.php$1 [R=301,L]
```

*Note that URL will be changed as follows*

http://hostname.com/mywebsite to http://hostname.com/app.php

http://hostname.com/mywebsite/test to http://hostname.com/app.php/test

http://hostname.com/mywebsite/something/another to http://hostname.com/app.php/something/another

**Case 2**: If you do not want a full redirection (ie., URL should not be changed), then you need to consider below points.

1. In this case requested URL will be preserved (ie., url should be something like `http://hostname.com/mywebsite/test`)
2. As end user should not be aware of whats going inside, then you `do not need to bypass your request to app.php/test` and thus no server overhead, *and instead bypass your request to app.php* (I'll explain the rest with PHP code below)

Simply use below rule

```
RewriteEngine On
#No redirection, bypass request to app.php
RewriteRule ^mywebsite(.*)$ app.php
```

Now you need to get parameters like `/test` and `/something/another` right? grab it using following code block.

```
$param = '';
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/mywebsite') === 0) {
    //10 => length of "/mywebsite"
    $param = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 10);
}

echo 'URL PARAM: ' . $param;
```

For the URL http://hostname.com/mywebsite $param will be empty string

and for http://hostname.com/mywebsite/test $param will be `/test`

and for http://hostname.com/mywebsite/something/another/1234 $param will be `/something/another/1234`

*Note that I've just avoided unwanted conditional request-bypasses, and just bypassed all requests to app.php without any parameters (since parameters are there along with URL)*

You can see `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will hold value something like `/something/another/1234` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` will be similar to `/app.php/something/another/1234`

Hope this can solve your problem...

Comment: A really good explanations! I like your version 1 but without showing app.php to the user (no redirection?). Is this possible to do it?

Comment: @TroodoN-Mike sure!!! I've tested above htaccess entries on my server too... :)

One more thing... Almost all frameworks of PHP uses the same technique (hide from user, the fact of from where code executes)

Comment: so, for case 1 should i remove relocate [R] not to show app.php in the url?

Comment: I would say its meaningless...
Case 1 is redirecting all requests to `app.php/the-rest-of-param`.
If you do not want to show app.php in url, then why are you bypassing request to `app.php/the-rest-of-param`, you just need to handle all request with app.php

Comment: To be honest, your answer did help me to understand my problem. I ended up with rooting all traffic ^(.)*$ to my app.php file and because i use symfony2 i have added route with prefix "/mywebsite". Thanks

Comment: @TroodoN-Mike - Congratz... "/mywebsite" is more accurate, and you did it in the right way... :)